# Is there any mention of Shiva agrees to take Ganga into his hair in Shiva Purana?

Tags: shiva, puranas, shiva-purana, ganga

Is there any mention of Shiva agrees to take Ganga into his hair so as to prevent her mighty flow from destroying the Earth in shiva purana.